# php array search values if exist

Tags: php, arrays

```
[{id: 1, group: core},{id: 2, group: elite},{id: 3, group: elite},{id: 4, group: elite}]
```

How to check if an id already exits in the array?

I tried 
`in_array(array('id' => 2), $myarray)` but it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **array_column** function to extract one column from array and then search for value, like this:

```
in_array(2, array_column($myarray, 'id'));
```

This assume that you convert that JSON to associative array and not array of objects.

**WARNING:** This function is available only on PHP 5.5 and newer, so you can use this workaround for older versions, where function is not exists (on 5.5+ it will use native fast implementation instead):

```
if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
  function array_column($array, $column_key) {
    $ret = array();
    foreach ($array as $item)
      $ret[] = $item[$column_key];
    return $ret;
  }
}
```

Comment: Just edited answer and added warning about PHP version, please consider this restriction too, because PHP 5.5 is still not standard in lot of webhosting companies.

Answer (score 1):

you must pass all array:

```
in_array(array('id' => 2, 'group' => 'elite'), $myarray)
```

Comment: Nice but the other array containing id 2 have different value in group.